# Switching sub components in and out of a component in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a sidebar that has some sub-components that could have their visibility toggled. The components need to restart their state when being shown.

Can I just use ng-show? Some of the components have a lot of data and observables so it could be expensive to just hide them in the background.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to go with *ngIf, since using it will remove elements from DOM. This means that all your handlers or anything else attached to those elements will be lost.